# the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel, even adding the code for the tls protocols don't work

Tags: vb.net, security, ssl

I am trying to connect to an URL using vb, add the code:

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = True
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

But still got the error: "the request was aborted could not create ssl/tls secure channel"
Which other factor can cause this?

Comment: The lack of matching cipher suites. Some Web sites allow only the more recent cipher suites. See the lists here: [TLS Cipher Suites in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel). If your System is Windows 7 or Server 2008 R2 (end-of-life reached), then no luck (unrelated: you should set `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False`, unless you have code to handle it, that is). If you're about to say: *but the WebBrowser can get there*, well, most WebBrowsers have their own cipher suites (and handle those on their own).